# How to set up a cron job in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, cron, discord.js

I would like to set up a message to auto-repeat in a channel once a day at the same time. My research has shown me that using cron is the best solution. The problem is I don't know how to set it up within my discord bots framework. It won't be a command, I want it completely autonomous. Do I need to make a new folder for it? Or put it in my main handler file? I can't find any tutorials out there that show how to integrate cron into a Discord.js code.

Any suggestions or tutorials you can link me to would be much appreciated

Comment: [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples](Here)

Comment: That link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with `node-cron`.

Here is an example:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples

Comment: Yeah I have read those before, but I don't understand how to integrate it into my discord bot

Comment: You have to install it with npm (node package manager) and then integrate it as shown in the tutorial. Maybe the [documentation](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron) helps.